# Are there any fonts with various styles for the same letter?

Tags: fonts

Allow me to explain. Imagine a font where "t" is different depending on the letter preceding it, or following it. Same with, for example, "y". Can that be done?

Comment: Have you done any research yourself, and what were your findings?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Can a typeface be designed to have characters depend on previous characters within a typed word?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/82036/can-a-typeface-be-designed-to-have-characters-depend-on-previous-characters-with)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it can be done. The most common example would be ligatures, which are found in fonts that support open type. You can [read more about it here](http://ilovetypography.com/OpenType/opentype-features.html).

Comment: Please do not just post a link as answers to questions should be able to live without relying on an external link and links can go bad, which is known as link rot.  Explain your link or your question will be removed, thanks.